# MySQL giving me a syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with my MySQL query. I get an error that I cannot fix, and still need some help.
This is my code in my PHP script (show_messages.php):

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
$username = @$_GET['user'];
$password = @$_GET['password'];
$message_from = @$_GET['from'];
$message_to = @$_GET['to'];

if(($login = login($username, $password)) != 1) {
    echo $login; // return the value of the error
    exit;
} else {
    $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from LIKE $message_from AND to LIKE $message_to ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 50");
    $rows = @mysql_numrows($mysql);
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error().'<br/>';
    if($rows > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $rows) {
            $result_content = mysql_result($mysql, $i, 'content');
            $result_from = mysql_result($mysql, $i, 'from');
            echo $result_from.'<br/>'.$result_content.'<br/><br/>';
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No messages.';
    }
}

?>
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from LIKE 8 AND to LIKE 1 ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 50' at line 1
```

This is my database structure:
[Image of my DB structure](http://puu.sh/3mFNW.png)

I don't know what to do. I am developing an app, and I just can't move on without fixing this issue beforehand.
Thanks in advance.

(If anyone knows how to make the other code better, feel free to correct me, I am not a professional, I am only 15 years old :P)

**EDIT 2:**
If anyone can help me on another thing, I am getting a warning on this line:

```
$rows = mysql_numrows($mysql);
```

I have to change it to `$rows = @mysql_numrows($mysql);` so it won't show the warning, but it's still a warning, and if anyone is kind enough to help me resolve it, please do. Thanks again.

Comment: What does the `messages` table look like? Are `from` and `to` numbers or strings?

Comment: I rewrote the whole question, and attached a link to an image. I can provide my whole SQL dump of that table. I just created it yesterday. Thanks.

Comment: The word `from` (your column name) is a reserved word. You need to put backticks around it like this `\`from\``. You'll also want to put single quotes around the variables in the SQL string.

Comment: @MaxMackie, that works. Thanks. If you want, make an answer and I will select it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I added my comment as an answer.

Comment: @user0000001 - In the future programming questions should remain on Stackoverflow, after the revisions that added all the code, this really should have been migrated in June.  Since its past that time, keep the question how it is, but its well researched so i issued a upvote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word from (your column name) is a reserved word. You need to put backticks around it like this `` `from` ``. You'll also want to put single quotes around the variables in the SQL string.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [**Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) for column names in MySQL use backticks ie ` to escape.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from=`8` AND to=`1` ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I am going to edit my question right now and add my code + DB structure.

Comment: Just edited the question. Looking forward to an answer. :D

Comment: @Vlad1k you should ask a new question  instead of editing existing question